# Building a large 6GB .JAR file using Maven

Tags: file, maven, jar, build, large-files

I made a project that is 6GB size. I'm trying to build a .JAR file but I get this following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins: maven-assembly-plugin:3.0.0:single 
(make-assembly) on project ProjectName: Failed to create assembly: 
Error creating assembly archive jar-with-dependencies: 
archive's ZIP64 end of central directory locator is corrupt. -> [Help 1]
```

.jar file builds and runs well if one large folder is excluded or resized to ~3GB. It seems like something is wrong with ZIP64 archiving format and my project's pom.xml file

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Project name</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Application</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why are you creating such a massive `jar` file in the first place?

Comment: Don't know any other way to build and run my project on a VM. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean you're packaging your VM inside the `jar` with your code? You haven't really provided sufficient information on what your use case is. What do you want to do? Why? Etc...

Comment: Ok, sorry - I made a web application that stores 3D virtual tour which size is 6gb. I want to build this project as a .jar file, then put and start it in VM. Everything works fine when those large files are excluded. Something is wrong with my pom.xml, zip64 isn't able to archive my project correctly. Or something. :/

Comment: So, ok - my problem seems to be springboot. I left only two plugins: maven-compiler-plugin and spring-boot-maven-plugin. It works fine when building 3GB project, but doesn't work with my 6GB files.

Comment: So this reduces the root cause to the spring-boot-maven-plugin...I assume they don't use the most recent versions of plexus-archiver / maven-archiver or commons archiver...Cause I'm using maven-assembly-plugin to create 15 GiB size zip archives which works fine...

Comment: And that means I just can't archive such big .jar file? What should I do?